# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException excepton when switching and getting CurrentURL of window on Linux amd64 OS

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

**org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException**

```
Build info:
17:31:52 System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.109-104.500.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.19'
selenium version: '4.13.0*

Browser/Driver: Chrome/ChromeDriver
Rinning with headless **`options.addArguments("--headless");`**

`Nov 20, 2023 11:58:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
17:28:03 WARNING: The chromedriver version (113.0.5672.63) detected in PATH at /usr/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (114.0.5735.198); currently, chromedriver 114.0.5735.90 is recommended for chrome 114.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
17:28:03 Driver Location/usr/bin/chromedriver
17:28:03 Nov 20, 2023 11:58:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
17:28:03 WARNING: The chromedriver version (113.0.5672.63) detected in PATH at /usr/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (114.0.5735.198); currently, chromedriver 114.0.5735.90 is recommended for chrome 114.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
17:28:03 Nov 20, 2023 11:58:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
17:28:03 WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 114
17:28:03 Nov 20, 2023 11:58:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
17:28:03 WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 114.0.5735.198. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.13.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Getting below exception when switching to new window and getting `currentURL`

```
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Can anyone help to review and know why this expectation occurring.

**Exception:**

```
17:31:52 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
17:31:52 Build info: version: '4.13.0', revision: 'ba948ece5b*'
17:31:52 System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.109-104.500.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.19'
17:31:52 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
17:31:52 Command: [1d9bc8563bbe6934a6c2c66d3e761fc8, getCurrentUrl {}]
17:31:52 Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 114.0.5735.198, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.877XX8}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:35993}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:35993/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 114.0.5735.198, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
17:31:52 Session ID: 1d9bc8563bbe6934a6c2c66d3e761fc8
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:65)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:55)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:48)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:96)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:188)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:675)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:679)
17:31:52    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getCurrentUrl(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
```

Tried with `options.addArguments("--headless=new");` 
But here window size is not getting applied i.e. `options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");`

Comment: You can provide more context to the question.
It is quite not clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @wpnpeiris when I'm using `options.addArguments("--headless")` statement for headless browser and switch window tab. I'm getting the exception `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64'